# PyQt5 QPixmap scaled origin

Tags: python, image, pyqt5, qpixmap

I have needed to create a tool that can gather pixel values for the corners of a box of an image. I have decided to use PyQt5 for this as it is what I am most familiar with. I have used QPixmap for this and the `scaled` function to scale an image for zooming in and out with the scroll wheel. When I zoom however, the zoom always zooms to the same point and I am struggling to find a way to change the zoom origin. Thanks

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, Qt, QTime, QDateTime, QPoint, QRect, QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QWidget, QCalendarWidget,
                         QLabel, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QTextEdit,
                         QFileDialog, QAction, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout,
                         QGridLayout, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QTextEdit,
                         QPlainTextEdit, QRubberBand)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap

import os, sys

class App(QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.title = 'BoundingBoxQT'
    self.left = 1000
    self.top = 100
    self.width = 748
    self.height = 1402
    self.initUI()



def initUI(self):

    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

    # Create widget
    self.label = QLabel(self)
    self.pixmap = QPixmap('BALMRCRTLOA_trisected.png')
    self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
    self.label.resize(self.pixmap.width(),self.pixmap.height())

    self.show()
    

    #getting the positio of the mouse click
    self.mousePressEvent = self.ClickPosition
    self.mouseReleaseEvent = self.ReleasePosition
    self.mouseMoveEvent = self.Move

    self._band = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
    self._band.show()

    self.scale = 1

    self.wheelEvent = self.ScrollWheel
    self.scrollcount = 0
    
def ClickPosition(self, event):
    self.origin = event.pos()
    x = event.pos().x()
    y = event.pos().y()

    print(x,y)

def Move(self, event):
    self._band.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, event.pos()).normalized())

def ReleasePosition(self, event):
    x = event.pos().x()
    y = event.pos().y()
    print(x,y)

def ScrollWheel(self,event):
    result = event.angleDelta().y()
    x = event.pos().x()
    y = event.pos().y()

    if result < 0:
        self.zoom_out(self.wheelEvent,x,y)
    elif result > 0:
        self.zoom_in(self.wheelEvent,x,y)

def zoom_in(self,event,x,y):
    if self.scrollcount == 7:
        return
    self.scale *= 1.5
    self.scrollcount += 1
    self.resize(x,y)

def zoom_out(self,event,x,y):

    if self.scrollcount == 0:
        return
    self.scale /= 1.5
    self.scrollcount -= 1
    self.resize(x,y)

def resize(self,x,y):
    size = self.label.size() # maybe remove the self if wrong
    scaled = self.pixmap.scaled(self.scale*size)
    
    self.label.setPixmap(scaled)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = App()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Use the [graphics view framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html) and do not overwrite events with custom functions, as it's both pointless and prone to unexpected behavior. Besides, only classes and constants should have capitalized names.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, I'm not the most proficient programmer but thank you very much.